# Stop asp.net web form load event finished, webform load event processing again and again

Tags: asp.net, events, webforms, load

I have a webform page, when the page clicked by the user the form load event firing, on the form load event I take session data update db and then I return the webform with return keyword. With my surprise the load event again firing.
I give `Response.end()`; it is not working.
In the webform I have only asp.net label and textbox control one button control only.

Any solution or idea?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check postback
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        String username = String.Empty;
        double amount = 0.0;

        try
        {
            //check user session
            if ((Session["username"] != null) && (Session["amount"] != null))
            {
                username = Convert.ToString(Session["username"]);
                amount = Convert.ToDouble(Session["amount"]);
                //assign session user name
                lblUserName.Text = username;
                lblTranAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(amount);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            txtError.Visible = true;
            txtError.Text = "your payment successfull " +" \n" +"We could not update the papercut due to User session Not Available: " + e1.Message + " " + e1.Source;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e1.Message + "\n" + e1.Source);
            return;
        }

        //check user balance
        ServerCommandProxy serverProxy = null;
        double tempCurrentBalance = 0.0;
        try
        {
            serverProxy = new ServerCommandProxy("217.206.49.71", 9191, "netm0an");//server 217.206.49.71
            tempCurrentBalance = serverProxy.GetUserAccountBalance(username, "");
            lblCurrentBalance.Text = Convert.ToString(tempCurrentBalance);
            //
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            lblCurrentBalance.Text = "Due to Erro not able update";
            txtError.Visible = true;
            txtError.Text = "your payment successfull " + " \n " + "We could not update the papercut balance amount Due to the below Exception : " + "\n " + "XML Web service API access violations: due to Server IP Address: 217.206.49.71 " + "\n " + e2.Message + " \n " + e2.Source;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e2.Message + "\n" + e2.Source);
            return;
        }
        //update papercut balance by xml rpc api
        try
        {
            //listuseraccounts

           // String [] accounts  = serverProxy.ListUserAccounts(0, 1000);

            serverProxy.AdjustUserAccountBalance(username, amount, "Ogone Payment updated Balance: $" + (tempCurrentBalance + amount), "Default");
            double totalBalance = (tempCurrentBalance + amount);
            lblTotalBalance.Text = Convert.ToString(totalBalance);

            serverProxy = null;
            Session["username"] = null;
            Session["amount"] = null;
            username = string.Empty;
            amount = 0.0;
           return;// after this line form loading again why?


        }
        catch (Exception e3)
        {
            lblTotalBalance.Text = "Due to Error not able update";
            txtError.Visible = true;
            txtError.Text = "your payment successfull "  +" \n " + "We could not update the papercut balance amount Due to the below Exception : " + "\n " + "XML Web service API access violations: due to Server IP Address: 217.206.49.71 " + "\n " + e3.Message + " \n " + e3.Source;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e3.Message + "\n" + e3.Source);
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sebastien Sevrin, what you edited, I did not understand, Please give me/post to me.

Comment: Thank you Sebastien , how to write question, Now I have seen the edited question by you, thank you

Comment: Try setting AutoEventWireup to true in the @Page directive, then removing Handles MyBase.Page_Load, Me.Load from the Page_Load, in all the solutions files.